# Expected Initializer Before Function (Easy Fix?)

Tags: c++, string

Hey guys I'm pretty new to the whole C++ thing and I am currently writing a program where I am getting the error "error: expected initializer before ‘function’" coming from java I don't really understand what I am doing wrong as I pass doMath a string and then try to work with that string. I have tried storing what I get from the .at(0) in a string and a char but neither have worked. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

 //pass string with leading operator and arguments
int doMath(const string function){
int answer = -1;
char operator = function.at(0);
    if(operator.compare("*") == 0){
        for(int i = 1; i < function.length(); i++){
            if(i < 1){
                answer = stoi(function.at(i));
            }
            else{
                answer = answer * stoi(function.at(i));
            }
        }
    }
        //etc. etc. etc.
}`
```

Comment: See the list of [reserved words in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword), paying close attention to `operator`. Change it to anything *not* on that list (like `op`). And btw, `char` has no member named `compare` (in fact it has no members *at all*), so you probably want `if (op == '*')` instead.

Comment: In future it'd be good to post the exact error message (including the bit where it shows which line generated the error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`operator` is a keyword in C++. You should call your variable something else.

Hopefully if you use an editor with syntax highlighting, it will highlight keywords.